# Fonts not showing with ubuntu studio 14.04.4 and LCD TV, can you help me?

Tags: nvidia, display, fonts, hdmi, ubuntu-studio

I'm using an LCD TV as monitor and ubuntu Studio 14.04.4; can't see fonts properly and most of the tweaks and tricks haven't worked so far. I have a geforce gtx 750 ti and using the HDMI cable.  I've tried some of the recommendations but the commands are not recognized. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly you're probably going to just need to get an actual monitor with VGA, DVI, or DisplayPort. Blurry fonts over an HDMI connection is just part of how HDMI works, and why it's not usually a good choice for a monitor connection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made a big mistake, (newbie) but it was all due to not having the proper drivers, even blender and steam were making the system crash.  Once the right drivers were installed (352.63), it works like a charm and I can see textures I didn't know were there.  Thanks but it was user related issue, I have a lot to learn. n_n